# Trouble with unique_ptr : not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a hard time finding why compiler tell me this:

```
main.cpp:51:17: error: ‘unique_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
 static std::unique_ptr<Pizza> createPizza(PizzaType t_pizza)
```

and this:

```
main.cpp:69:5: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
 std::unique_ptr<Pizza> pizza = PizzaFactory::createPizza(t_pizzaType);
```

I have the include for unique_ptr

```
#include <memory>
```

and I use the good C++ compilation flags

```
CFLAGS  =   -std=c++11 -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
```

I have already try **using namespace std**;

Here are the block of code where I use **std::unique_ptr**

```
class PizzaFactory
{
 public:
  enum PizzaType
  {
  Hawaiian,
  Vegetarian,
  Carnivoro
  };

  static std::unique_ptr<Pizza> createPizza(PizzaType t_pizza)
  {
  switch (t_pizza)
  {
  case Hawaiian:
    return std::unique_ptr<HawaiianPizza>(new HawaiianPizza());
  case Vegetarian:
    return std::unique_ptr<VegetarianPizza>(new VegetarianPizza());
  case Carnivoro:
    return std::unique_ptr<CarnivoroPizza>(new CarnivoroPizza());
  default:
    throw "Invalid pizza type.";
  }
  }
};

void pizza_information(PizzaFactory::PizzaType t_pizzaType)
{
  std::unique_ptr<Pizza> pizza = PizzaFactory::createPizza(t_pizzaType);
  std::cout << "Price of " << t_pizzaType << "is " << pizza->getPrice() << '\n';
}
```

I really can find what's wrong with this code, please help

Thank you.

**edit.**

Here is the Makefile I use:

```
NAME    =   plazza

G++ =   g++

CFLAGS  =   -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11

SRC =   main.cpp

OBJ =   $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

RM  =   rm -rf

all:    $(NAME)

$(NAME):    $(OBJ)
    $(G++) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBj)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(NAME)

re: fclean  all
```

**edit2.**

Here a smal code that give me the same errors:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Hi
{
    public:
        void sayHi(const std::string &t_hi)
        {
            std::cout << t_hi << '\n';
        }
};

int main()
{
    auto hi = std::unique_ptr<Hi>(new Hi());

    hi->sayHi("Salut");
    return 0;
}
```

compile with the Makefile above you should have the error

Comment: *Where* do you include `<memory>`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: It seems like you have `#include` in your make file instead of source file

Comment: Asking the obvious:  Have you defined the classes `Pizza`, `HawaiianPizza`, `VegetarianPizza`, and `CarnivoroPizza` in your source or declared them in a header you're including?

Comment: All the code is in an unique main.cpp file and I have define all the class I needed

Comment: When building with your makefile, take a look at the output and the command it creates for the building of the object files. Aren't your flags missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CFLAGS` is for C compilers. You are using C++ and a C++ compiler. Use `CXXFLAGS` in your Makefile to set C++ compiler's flags:

```
NAME    =   plazza

G++ =   g++

CXXFLAGS  =   -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11

SRC =   main.cpp
```

Since you are setting C flags, C++11 is not enabled because `-std=c++11` is not passed to your C++ compiler. If you compiled with a C compiler, the compiler (at least GCC does it AFAIK) would warn about the C++ flag being set on the C compiler. You could use `make VERBOSE=1` in these kind of compiler error situations for debugging.

Comment: Thank you sir, it work. I didn't know that the name of variables in a Makefile matters. Thank again

Comment: @MockingBird You're welcome. On StackExchange sites, if the answers solves your problem, you should mark them as the accepted answer so that the question gets closed (it can be done below voting button).

Answer (score 20):

Try adding

```
#include <memory>
```

To the top of your file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating cmake project, you can add a line of code to CmakeLists.txt as shown below.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -std=c++11")
```

Ethereal has explained the details of the reason for the error.